# Change Cell Color Based on Specific RGB Values in the Same Row

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I have an Excel spreadsheet using about 1200 rows and 5 columns. The A column contains names of colors. The B, C and D columns contain the Red, Green and Blue values of those colors. The E column is empty, but I would like each cell in the E column to be colored with the color with RGB values equal to those in the B, C and D columns in that row.

I have very little experience with VBA, and I have found no solutions in my searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks pnuts, that link put me on the right track. For any interested, I added

```
For i as integer = 2 to 1200
    Cells(i, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 2))
Next i
```

within the Worksheet Change event.